# Send message to Azure IoT Device over intranet

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

I have one IoT device (Raspberry pi) connected over internal network (wihtout internet connectivity).

I have one intranet web application running in the same network.

Now I want to send a message from web application to switch ON the lights to IoT device and that device should switch ON the lights.

Is there any solution supported by the Azure IoT edge? Azure IoT client?